# Route controller that is in a sub folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 project with a "sub" folder inside my `Controllers` folder. Now i want to create a Route to a controller that is inside that subfolder. But how can i do that?

This doesn't seem to work for me:

```
context.MapRoute("Test", "SubFolder/Test",
            new { Controller = "SubFolder/Test", Action = "Index" });
```

So the name of the subfolder is `SubFolder` and in there i have a controller called `TestController.cs`. How can i create a MapRoute for that?

Comment: Did you try using your controller without setting any special routes and it failed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such notion as subfolder for controllers. Controllers are just C# classes which you could store wherever you want. In your route configuration you should only mention the controller name:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Test", 
    "SubFolder/Test",
    new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" }
);
```

and if you wanted to have 2 controllers with the same name, you need to specify the namespace constraint when defining the route:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Test", 
    "SubFolder/Test",
    new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" },
    new[] { "MvcApplication.Controllers.SubFolder" }
);
```

So now when you navigate to `http://example.com/subfolder/test`, the Index action of the TestController will be executed.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I thought i had to write down the path to the controller, but the controller name was indeed enough.

Comment: No, the second argument represents the URL pattern.

Comment: You should use the namespaces constraint as shown in my answer if you want to have 2 controllers with the same name. On the other hand they should be mapped to different route patterns. Up to you to decide the format of your urls.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [MvcCodeRouting](https://github.com/maxtoroq/MvcCodeRouting), you can nest controllers in subfolders as deep as you want and the routing will be based on the namespaces, so will follow the convention of the folders by default.

```
using System.Web.Routing;
using MvcCodeRouting;

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {

    routes.MapCodeRoutes(typeof(Controllers.HomeController));
}
```

[Getting Started with MvcCodeRouting](https://github.com/maxtoroq/MvcCodeRouting/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started.md)